# Unable to view retrieved images from database onto ImageView

Tags: database, windows, javafx, imageview

This query is about a difference in **behavior of Retrieving Images from Database and setting it to JavaFx ImageView** - In a Local machine (where coding was done) against another computer which was used for testing.

**[PROGRAM OUTPUT IN LOCAL MACHINE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmksY.jpg)**

**[PROGRAM OUTPUT IN THE TEST MACHINE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oewg8.jpg)**

As seen in the screenshots retrieved images from db are set to the respective ImageViews when executed in the local machine, however images are not visible once the same program  is executed in the test machine even though the image names appear in the tableView columns.

Below is the code to browse for and save the images:

```
 try(InputStream is = rs.getBinaryStream("IMAGE1")) {
 OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("photo1.jpg"));
 byte[] content = new byte[1024];
 int size = 0;
 while((size = is.read(content)) != -1) {
 os.write(content, 0, size);}
 os.close();
 }

 image1 = new Image("file:photo1.jpg");
 imgvw.setImage(image1);
```

What is missing in the test machine?

Comment: Does it work if you don't try to create the URL yourself? I.e. do `File file = new File("photo1.jpg"));`. Then do `OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file));` and later `image1 = new Image(file.toURI().toString());`. (And do you actually need to save it to a file at all? Why not do `image1 = new Image(is);`?)

Comment: You close `os` in the loop body but create it outside of said body... This does not seem reasonable... Furthermore why do you use try-with resources with only one stream instead of both??? `try(InputStream is = rs.getBinaryStream("IMAGE1");
 OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("photo1.jpg"))) { ...`

Comment: Hi James_D, to be precise the above snippet is to save the binary data into a COLUMN named IMAGE1, there is a separate method to browse & select a desired image.                                                                     The code I'm using seems alright when used locally, I'm interested to find out how to retain the same behaviour even outside of the development system.

Comment: @fabian The stream is closed outside the loop (it's just that the OP couldn't be bothered to lay the code out in a readable way).

Comment: @Berch That doesn't actually answer either of my questions.